# How can I inherit from dynamically created classes whilst maintaining type safety in Python?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

## The situation

I have a function that I'm using to dynamically create classes, some of which I inherit from.

```py
def createType(extends: type[T]) -> type[T]:
    def constructor(self, s: str) -> None:
        self.s = s

    def stringify(self) -> str:
        return self.s

    def thing(self) -> None:
        print("Hello")

    return type(  # type: ignore
        f"MyType{extends.__name__}",
        (extends,),
        {
            '__init__': constructor,
            '__str__': stringify,
            'thing': thing,
        }
    )

TypeA = createType(object)

class TypeB(TypeA):
    ...
```

## The problem

When I create the derived class, I get an error in mypy.

```py
class TypeB(TypeA):
#           ^^^^^ Invalid base class "TypeA"
```

As well as this, I can't get intellisense predictions on instances of `TypeA` or `TypeB`.

```py
b = TypeB()
b.thing()  # Not suggested
```

How can I cleanly fix the mypy errors and get intellisense predictions for my code?

## What I've tried

### 1.

I've tried using typevars for the return values of the `createType` function. This doesn't solve either issue

### 2.

I've tried creating a mock interface type, then using an `if TYPE_CHECKING` check to redefine it.

```py
class MyInterface:
    def __init__(self, s: str) -> None:
        ...

    def thing(self) -> None:
        ...

if not TYPE_CHECKING:
    TypeA = createType(Thing)
else:
    TypeA = MyInterface
```

While this allows me to get type hints for the added methods, it doesn't work for the original type, and it means that I'm adding a bunch of extra duplicate code.

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72100265/python-generic-that-adds-typed-functionality-to-extend-existing-types-incorrectl/72177389#72177389). The easiest solution will be to define in `if TYPE_CHECKING:` block `class TypeA(MyInterface, <another_base>)` (like you did with assignment) and use it as superclass of `TypeB`. You need `Intersection` type which is not implemented yet (and is not likely to be in the nearest future).

Comment: @SUTerliakov so I was on the right track with my second attempted solution?

Comment: Yes, you were almost done: just use subclass of `MyInterface` and target base instead of assigning pure `MyInterface`.