Mypy + FlaskSQLAlchemy + model multiple inheritance => has no attribute
It seems that mypy is having problems taking into account all the superclasses and reports missing attributes. Here is a simple example:
import uuid

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import String
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import UUID
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column, DeclarativeBase


db = SQLAlchemy()


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class IdMixin:
    id = mapped_column(UUID(as_uuid=True), nullable=False, default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)


class ImageMixin:
    image_name = mapped_column(String, default=None)
    image_uri = mapped_column(String, default=None)


class Model(IdMixin, Base):
    pass


class Post(Model, ImageMixin):
    content = mapped_column(String)


class Comment(Model, ImageMixin):
    text = mapped_column(String)


def generate_image_uri(image_name: str) -> str:
    return f"https://example.com/{image_name}"


models = [Comment, Post]
for model in models:
    entities = db.session.query(model).all()
    for entity in entities:
        entity.image_uri = generate_image_uri(image_name=entity.image_name) # Line 45

Mypy reports:
mypy-warning.py:45: error: "Model" has no attribute "image_uri"  [attr-defined]
mypy-warning.py:45: error: "Model" has no attribute "image_name"  [attr-defined]

It works just fine when I move the ImageMixin to the Model class and then only subclass Model in the Post and Comment classes, but this is not what I want as I don't necessarily want all models to mix in the image functionality.

Mypy infers the type of the List containing Post and Comment as:
builtins.list[def (**kw: Any) -> t.Model]

Which makes sense as both Post and Comment inherit from Model (And is also the reason why Mypy doesn't complain when you move the ImageMixin to the Model class).
Explicitely annotating the list with:
models: list[type[ImageMixin]] = [Comment, Post]

fixes the error and now only allows Classes with inherit from ImageMixin to be used in the list and therefore ensuring that the image_url attribute is accessible when accessed in the following for loop.

Thank you! That works indeed. A follow up question—would it be possible to provide two types in place of type[ImageMixin]? E.g. a list of objects that inherit from both IdMixin and ImageMixin?
EDIT: I just tried Union[IdMixin, ImageMixin] and it worked, but I thought Union means either or, whereas I was interested in both.

To the meaning of Union: "Union[t1, t2, …]. Types that are subtype of at least one of t1 etc. are subtypes of this." (taken from PEP483)

@koleS no, you can't express that now - what you need is an Intersection type, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72100265/python-generic-that-adds-typed-functionality-to-extend-existing-types-incorrectl/72177389#72177389. Not implemented, not likely to land any soon.
